# How can I correctly output a card with v-for?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, frontend

I have an array of records. It has 40 records, 8 records for each day,I created card with 2 section,to output it,I need to write first record output in first section , and other 7 in another section,then I have to output next 8, and continue up to the end.

```html
<div class = "container-fluid" v-else>

  <section class="vh-100" style="background-color: #C1CFEA;">
  <div class="container py-5 h-100">
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100" style="color: #282828;">
      <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-7 col-xl-5">

        <div class="card mb-4 gradient-custom" style="border-radius: 25px;" v-for ="(item,index) in weatherList" :key="item.dt_txt">
          <div class="card-body p-4">
            <div id="demo1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
              <!-- Indicators -->
              <ul class="carousel-indicators mb-0">
                <li data-target="#demo1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#demo1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#demo1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
              </ul>
              <!-- Carousel inner -->
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between mb-4 pb-2">
                    <div>
                      <h2 class="display-2"><strong>{{item.main.temp}}°C</strong></h2>
                      <p class="text-muted mb-0 ms-0">{{ cityName }}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/new-templates/bootstrap-weather/ilu3.webp"
                        width="20px" height="20px">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="demo2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <!-- Indicators -->
                    <ul class="carousel-indicators mb-0">
                        <li data-target="#demo2" data-slide-to="0"></li>
                        <li data-target="#demo2" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#demo2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- Carousel inner -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-around text-center mb-4 pb-3 pt-2">
                            <div class="flex-column" v-for ="(item1,sindex) in weatherList" :key="item1.dt_txt">
                                <div class = "wrapp" v-if ="sindex <= index+8">
                            <p class="small"><strong>{{item1.main.temp}}°C</strong></p>
                            <i class="fas fa-sun fa-2x mb-3" style="color: #ddd;"></i>
                            <p class="mb-0"><strong>{{ item1.dt_txt }}</strong></p>
                            <p class="mb-0 text-muted" style="font-size: .65rem;">PM</p>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
             </div>
          </div>
        </div>

          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    
    </section>
 </div>
```

I tried to wind out ways to use steps in for loop but didnt find them in `v-for`,tried to operate with indexes and `v-if` but didnt manage.

Comment: is the provided html just a part of the component template? `v-else` at the container div makes the question confusing. plus what didn't manage? are you getting any errors specifically?

Answer (score 0):

Boiling it down to what I believe is the crux of the issue: How to make 5 cards with 8 sections each from an array of 40 elements, where section 1 should stand out from the other 7.

My solution:

1. Use `v-for` to loop `array.length / 8` (one loop for each card).
2. Make a nested `v-for` to loop a sliced subarray of the overall array where each slice is a different 8 items.
3. Use `v-if="index % 8 == 0"` to differentiate between the first element vs. the other 7.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="i in arr.length / 8" :key="i" class="card">
      <div v-for="(item, j) in subArr(i)" :key="item.id">
        <div v-if="j % 8 == 0" class="section1">{{ item }}</div>
        <div v-else class="section2">{{ item }}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      arr: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    subArr(i) {
      const start = (i - 1) * 8;
      return this.arr.slice(start, start + 8);
    },
  },
  created() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
      this.arr.push({ id: i });
    }
  },
};
</script>

<style>
.card {
  margin: 20px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 50vw;
}
.section1 {
  background-color: darkolivegreen;
}
.section2 {
  background-color: darkcyan;
}
</style>
```

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-yhfm16?file=src%2FApp.vue&terminal=dev)